# Defining namespaced member vs free functions without qualification

Tags: c++, namespaces

I sometimes declare classes in nested namespaces and when it comes to defining their member functions, I prefer not to have to qualify each one with these  nested namespace names, especially if they are long-ish.

Adding "using namespace "  (or, for more precise targetting, "using ::SomeClass")  before I define the member functions seems to obviate the need to qualify each definition, but I can't find anywhere in the spec that guarantees this, and I'm worried that it might be a behaviour that only works with GCC.  I note that there doesn't appear to be a similar mechanism for skipping the need to add the qualifiers when defining free functions(?).

As an example of what I mean:

Header:

```
// example.h
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    class SomeClass
    {
    public:
        void someMemberFunction();
    };

    void someFreeFunction();
};
```

Implementation:

```
// example.cpp
#include "example.h"

using namespace SomeNamespace;

void SomeClass::someMemberFunction()
{
    // OK: seems to define SomeNamespace::SomeClass::someMemberFunction(),
    // even though we didn't qualify it with SomeNamespace::
}

void someFreeFunction()
{
    // Not what we wanted; declares and defines ::someFreeFunction(), not
    // SomeNamespace::someFreeFunction() (quite understandably)
}

int main()
{
    SomeClass a;
    a.someMemberFunction(); // Ok; it is defined above.
    SomeNamespace::someFreeFunction(); // Undefined!
    return 0;
}
```

So my question: is the above way of definining SomeClass::someMemberFunction() legal, and where in the spec is this mentioned?  If legal, is it advisable? It certainly cuts down on clutter! :)

Many thanks :)

Comment: Just out of interest: what is the problem with putting the definitions in a regular braced `namespace` ? (like you did with the declarations)

Comment: As long as you don't start using `using namespace ...` in headers you should be fine. Anyway, that's the intended use-case for `using` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a member-function, the compiler realizes that it is a member-function that must belong to a previously declared class, so it looks that class up, as specified in Section 9.3.5 of the standard:

> If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class
>   definition, the member function name shall be qualified by its class
>   name using the :: operator. [Note: a name used in a member function
>   definition (that is, in the parameter-declaration-clause including
>   the default arguments (8.3.6), or in the member function body, or, for
>   a constructor function (12.1), in a mem-initializer expression
>   (12.6.2)) is looked up as described in 3.4. ] [Example:
>
> ```
> struct X {
>     typedef int T; 
>     static T count; 
>     void f(T); 
> }; 
>
> void X::f(T t = count) { }
> ```
>
> The member function `f` of class `X` is defined in global scope; the
>   notation `X::f` specifies that the function `f` is a member of class `X` and
>   in the scope of class `X`. In the function definition, the parameter
>   type `T` refers to the typedef member `T` declared in class `X` and the
>   default argument count refers to the static data member count
>   declared in class `X`. ]

Basically, what you are doing is fine. However, there is another (preferable) way to cut down on the clutter when using nested namespaces, or namespaces with long names (or both) - define an alias:

```
namespace short_name = averylong::nested::namespacename;
```

Comment: Thanks! It's not clear to me from the standard-ese, though, that the "SomeClass" in the "SomeClass::someMethod" would be looked up in the way described in 3.4.  Is this definitely the case?

Comment: But don't use short since that is a datatype and as such a reserved keyword.

Comment: @MrLunchtime: Section 3.4 defines the name-lookup of C++. `SomeClass` is a name, so it is looked up like one.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm getting this wrong but if you have:

```
// example.h
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    class SomeClass
    {
    public:
        void someMemberFunction();
    };

    void someFreeFunction();
};
```

You can also simply write:

```
#include "example.h"

// example.cpp
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    void SomeClass::someMemberFunction()
    {
    }

    void someFreeFunction()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That's certainly one approach (and it seems one that is guaranteed to work), but I really dislike the clutter it adds (especially if you have nested namespaces).

Comment: @MrLunchtime: if it is only a matter of visual reasons ("i really dislike the clutter it adds"), perhaps the problem is not in the code, but in your text-editor's configuration ? I usually work with namespaces like that (sometimes nested), and disregard of the 3 added lines for the namespace declaration, it looks all the same.

Comment: That would  work, but (for purely reasons that are purely a matter of taste), I think I'd prefer to do the "using <nested namespaces>::SomeClass" method.  Thanks, though :)